# Derivative: Which rule to use first?

Tags: derivatives, exponentiation, products

> $f(x)=x^7(5+8x)^3$

Would I go about finding the derivative of this problem by using the chain rule first, and then the product rule? Or would I do the opposite? Step by step instructions would be immensely helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Product rule then chain rule.

Comment: Product and then chain rule

Comment: It is impossible to apply the chain rule here.

Answer (score 1):

You need both rules, but start of with product rule: $[x^7]'*(5+8x)^3+x^7*[(5x+8)^3]'$ In that last step you need Chain Rule which result in another factor 5. Can you work it out?

Comment: I tried to but can't seem to figure it out. I got 7x^6(5+8x)^3+x^7(75x+120) which isn't right

Comment: Where do you get that 75 and 120 from? I get a 24 in front of that term. See AmWhy's answer...

Answer (score 1):

Use the product rule first.

$$f(x)=x^7(5+8x)^3 \implies f'(x) = 7x^6(5+8x)^3 + x^7\cdot \frac{d}{dx}\left[(5 + 8x)^3\right]$$
Then, use the chain rule to evaluate the derivative of the remaining factor above:$$\frac{d}{dx}(5 + 8x)^3 = 3(5+8x)^2\cdot(8) = 24(5+8x)^2$$

Comment: You should start to think about accepting one answer to each of your questions ;-)